# Double integrals in polar coordinates as sum of slices for given angles?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For double integrals over rectangles I think an intuitive way to think about it is by either adding up the areas of the slices through the graph $(x,y,f(x,y))$ parallel to the x axis or adding up the areas of the slices parallel to the y axis.

That is if one was to think about it as adding the areas of slices parallel to the y axis, then if the rectangle is $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ for a given $x_0$ value the area of the slice is

$ \int_c^d f(x_0,y) dy $

Then "summing" over all the $x_0$ would intuitively give

$\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x,y)dydx$.

I thought this was a nice cute way to think about the double integral. However, extending this to integration over polar rectangle doesn't seem to work out. As such, I'm wondering if this "cute" approach above just coincidentally gives the right result, or if I'm missing something in extending it to a polar rectangle.

In the case of a polar rectangle, let's consider $\{(r,\theta)|\alpha\le \theta \le \beta, a \le r \le b \}$

Then I would think I could think about adding up the areas of slices across all $\theta$. That is, if I fix $\theta_0$ then the are of the slice through the graph $(x,y,f(x,y))$ on the polar rectangle, I would think, would be

$\int_a^b f(r\cos \theta_0, r\sin \theta_0) dr$

Then as above, summing all the slices over all the $\theta$ would give

$\int_\alpha^\beta\int_a^b f(r\cos \theta_0, r\sin \theta_0) dr\ d\theta$

but this is missing the factor of $r$. To be clear, I understand how to arrive at the correct formula by expressing it as a double sum and subdividing the polar rectangle into additional smaller polar rectangles.

To make matters worse, it seems like it would work out if I thought about it the other way, as fixing $r=r_0$ finding the area of the slice from varying $\theta$ and then summing over all $r$'s. That is, the area for a fixed $r_0$ would be

$\int_\alpha^\beta f(r_0\cos\theta,r_0\sin\theta)d\theta$

In some ways I'd like to blithely evaluate the above integral as is which would still yield the incorrect final double integral (i.e. once I tack on $\int_a^b$). However, I recognize that if I were to express it as a sum that the length of each rectangle would be $r \Delta \theta$ so I'd get my factor $r$.

So where am I missing my factor of $r$ when I look at $\int_a^b f(r\cos \theta_0, r\sin \theta_0) dr$? or is it incorrect to extend the cute slices picture (but I suspect you can since it seems to work out when I think about slices for a fixed $r_0$).